Nginx configured with subdomains but only returning root
I have some applications running in Docker and I am using Nginx as a reverse proxy. I want to set up a default domain like domain.com and www.domain.com to redirect to a React app, a subdomain admin.domain.com to redirect to container1, and api.domain.com to redirect to container2. However, currently, traffic from admin and api subdomains is being redirected to the default domain.
My current nginx.conf is:
events {}

http {
  include mime.types;

  map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
    default upgrade;
    '' close;
  }

  server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name domain.com www.domain.com;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/domain.com/privkey.pem;

    location / {
      root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
      index  index.html index.htm;
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
  }

  server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name api.domain.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/live/domain.com/privkey.pem;
    location / {
      proxy_pass http://container2:8080;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }
  }

  server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name admin.domain.com;

    auth_basic           "Protected Site";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/live/domain.com/privkey.pem;
    location / {
      proxy_pass http://container1:8080;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }
  }
}

I created three servers to handle each subdomain, but it didn't work. When I access admin.domain.com, the response doesn't come from container1; instead, it comes from the React application that should only be served at domain.com or www.domain.com. The same issue occurs for api.domain.com, where the response should come from container2 but is instead served by the React application.

can you include an error? please expand upon what you mean by "it didn't work"

@willwrighteng the issue is that when I access admin.domain.com, the response doesn't come from container1; instead, it comes from the React application that should only be served at domain.com or www.domain.com. The same issue occurs for api.domain.com, where the response should come from container2 but is instead served by the React application.

I was able to get a simple subdomain experiment working using the following setup:

note: I used dnsmasq to test this setup locally before I deployed the applications

.
├── docker-compose.yml
├── frontend1
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   ├── index.html
│   └── script.js
├── frontend2
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   ├── index.html
│   └── script.js
└── nginx
    ├── Dockerfile
    └── nginx.conf

docker-compose.yml
services:
  frontend1:
    build: ./frontend1
    ports:
      - "8081:80"

  frontend2:
    build: ./frontend2
    ports:
      - "8082:80"

  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - frontend1
      - frontend2


nginx.conf
events {}

http {
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name frontend1.test;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://frontend1:80;
        }
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name frontend2.test;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://frontend2:80;
        }
    }
}


each frontend contains a button with a js event listener that uses fetch to communicate with the other frontend
related post; and another

